# Create cron Expression from 8:30 to 12:30

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I want to create cron that run from 8:30 to 12:30 every one minute in MON,TUE,WED,SAT,SUN.

I create this expression:

```
0 30/1 8-12 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,SUN *
```

But not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use multiple cron expressions instead of just one.
Try this:

```
0 30-59 8 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN * // 8:30 - 8:59
0 * 9-11 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN * // 9:00 - 11:59
0 0-30 12 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN * // 12:00 - 12:30
```

Please note that Year field isn't mandatory, so you can omit the last field, like this:

```
0 30-59 8 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN // 8:30 - 8:59
0 * 9-11 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN // 9:00 - 11:59
0 0-30 12 ? * MON-WED,SAT,SUN // 12:00 - 12:30
```

Good luck!

Comment: Note you can also say `MON-WED,SAT,SUN`

Comment: @Shahrooz In Quartz, you can assign multiple triggers to a single job :)